# Dejo de Enviar Todo tipo de email

Tags: phpmailer

La respuestas del servidor que me da es

```html
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-host.dominioscaracas.com ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Mon, 09 Mar 2020 13:53:33 -0400 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-host.dominioscaracas.com Hello localhost [190.216.224.252] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK id=1jBMas-0042cO-HW
```

En si el codigo esta bien, de repente un momento a otro no me envia ningun email, probe con otra configuracion que igualmente me funcionaba y tampoco agarra

Comment: mandaste mails masivos? ahi hay un mensaje esclarecedor...

Comment: Mansivos no, siempre han sido para mi, son pruebas